Trying to put FNV64 converter from C# to Python, but stuck when multiplying ulong/int
I am trying to put code from C# to Python. I multiply long numbers with ulong in C# and it gives me not same result as in python. Python probably give me straight result, but in C# it's different
Here is example on C#
ulong a = 14695981039346656037;
ulong b = 1099511628211;
ulong c = a * b;

Result is c = 12638153115695167455
If I do same on Python, it gives me different results
a = 14695981039346656037
b = 1099511628211
c = a * b

Result is
c  = 16158402040730025834900042659807

I don't understand why it's different, but if it's possible to get on python same result? Is this something because of ulong?
I even don't know how to search for solution.
I need this results because I am trying to make code below, that makes FNV64 hash, from C# on Python
        string path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", locale, e);
        ulong basis = 14695981039346656037;
        ulong prime = 1099511628211;

        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(path);
        ulong hash = basis;
        foreach (byte b in byteData)
        {
            hash *= prime;
            hash ^= b;
        }
``


C# ulong is a 64-bit type, python integers are arbitrarily large. The C# code relies on the fact the unchecked unsigned integer multiplies are mod 2^64. If you want the same result, you should probably write a mult64() function for clarify that take the result mod 2^64, or simply (a * b) & 0xffffffffffffffff

Thank you very much, President James K. Polk! This is exactly what I needed!
